# работа с таймером в консоли

Tags: c#

Необходимо по таймеру в консоли выводить строку, причем каждый раз время тика должно меняться. Вот код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num = 0;
        // устанавливаем метод обратного вызова
        TimerCallback tm = new TimerCallback(Count);
        j = 1000;
        // создаем таймер
        Timer timer = new Timer(tm, num, 0, j);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static void Count(object obj)
    {
        int x = (int)obj;
        Console.WriteLine(j += 1000);

    }
```

И он не работает. Как поправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам нашел ответ

```
class Program
{
    private static int j;
    private static Timer timer;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num = 0;
        // устанавливаем метод обратного вызова
        TimerCallback tm = new TimerCallback(Count);
        j = 1000;
        // создаем таймер
        timer = new Timer(tm, num, 0, j);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static void Count(object obj)
    {
        int x = (int)obj;
        Console.WriteLine(j += 1000);
        timer.Change(j,0);
    }
}
```